# Google OAuth2 flow and id_token refresh

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-oauth

I am having troubles in implementing OAuth in the right way.
I use a client/API architecture (Angular for front and Node.js for back) and I would like user to sign in using Google OAuth authentication only.

Here is what I think is the right way for the moment (tell me if I misunderstood something) :

- Angular open a Google popup asking user's consent.
- Once the user agree, Google Authorization server sends back to angular a verification code.
- This verification code is forwarded to an API endpoint.
- Then, the API asks Google Authorization server to exchange this code for an access_token, an id_token and a refresh_token.
- Google sends those 3 tokens.
- The API uses access_token to retrieve user from Google API
- The API persists the user

Here is the little dillema, in my opinion, the access_token and refresh_token should be stored into the database and the id_token should be sent back to Angular client.
This way, it would allow the API to ask for resource in Google API and if the token expires it can still ask for a new token thanks to the refresh_token.
Client-side, the id_token is embedded in all requests thus allowing the API to identify the client and verify his authentication with Google certs from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs.

Supposing this is right way to use tokens, how could I deal with id_token expiration since client does not have any refresh token ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I do it slightly different (I have the same basic architecture though).

- Angular decides the user needs to log in and displays a login popup.
- The url in the login popup is *not* serviced by angular, but is instead directly run off of the backend server: `/auth/google` . (I use hapijs and bell, personally).
- `/auth/google` is serviced by a bell plugin and initiates the OAUTH dance.
- the end of the OAUTH dance results in my node server generating a local token (I just generate random bytes and store them in redis mapped to user ids)
- because the initial login popup was created by `window.open`, the success page (generated on the api side rather than in angular) can use `window.opener.postMessage` to communicate the token back to the angular runtime.

This way, all my sensitive google credentials (the user's oauth token, refresh token if needed, and my application's api ID and secret) are only on the server, except for during the OAUTH dance relay when they're in a URL string during the client redirects. This is reasonably secure.

Then for all the actual user interactions with the api, I use the token I generated in step four to authenticate. This could be a JWT if you wanted, but I don't do it that way; I just use redis to map from 'longrandostring' -> userId. That lets me (for example) force everyone to re-login if I wipe the redis database that has all the tokens stored, or I can write a lua script to delete all the entries that map to a certain userid.

If you need a refresh token, you can set `access_type=offline` in the initial request to `oauth2/auth`, and you'll get a refresh token as part of the response, unless you've previously gotten a refresh token. You can then persist it on the server side and get new access tokens as needed. If you set `approval_prompt=force` as well, you'll force a new consent screen and be guaranteed a refresh token (but after some small number of refresh tokens granted to a user, older ones expire on the same application so it's best to only request them if really needed).